# Canvas or SVG (or a blend) for large Org Chart

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, svg

The main question is pretty simple... I'm making a rather large Organization Chart (or genealogy) and I'm wondering whether I should be using SVG or Canvas.

Some of the requirements might sway the choice:

- Must be able to display between 1 to 50,000 nodes/people
- Needs to pan and zoom much like a Google/Bing map.
- Need to be able to click on a node and pop open a dialog with extra details on the person.

I was initially leaning towards SVG, but I heard somewhere that it would have performance problems when drawing a large number of items. Also, it seems Canvas has better support in older browsers.

Comment: I assume you mean you have up to 50k nodes you want to display data *from*, not at once? As you will need to buffer the view you can look into http://leafletjs.com and see if that can help you (org/gen. diagrams are maps in principle).

Comment: I need to show the shape of the tree, though I don't have to pull down all the data about each node all at once. When someone is looking at 50k nodes it would start out very much zoomed out.

Comment: Handling `onclick` events is much easier using SVG as each object has an actual DOM element associated with it.

Comment: One more note that I'll be sure to add to the original question above is that this Org Chart is highly changeable and I need also need to be able to show subsets of the full org chart.

Comment: I've done this a couple of years back. Wrote a web app: http://www.myfamilyhealth.com (try it, with a throw-away email if you want, registration is free). Back then I simply used divs and css to draw the chart. It's still implemented with divs and css. Our competitor used flash. We deliberately avoided flash in order to provide a more responsive experience. I tested it with the British royal family family tree which is rather large. If the tree is larger than 10 recursions up or down it doesn't draw the full tree but instead provides links for you to explore the far-away branches.

Comment: Hmm.. seems like they've removed GEDCOM file import and export on myfamilyhealth.com which would have been a quick way for you to load the tree with lots of nodes.

Comment: I actually did something similar 6 years ago. It worked well for 50 to 200 nodes, but then performance became a problem. I have the feeling though that SVG and Canvas are much more tuned for this problems set than good old divs. Thanks for the suggestion though!

Answer (score 2):

Thanks everyone for your input. The following is what I have come up with after exploring some of the advice given.

SVG: This route was very tempting due to its vectorized nature and its integration into the DOM. Sadly the performance of rendering +100k nodes killed this route.

Canvas: Performance wise this seemed to be a winner. However, at this point I will need to explore how to add onClick/onHover functionality to each of the rendered nodes.

Leaflet: This too is a winner. It takes care of a lot of concerns like the map-like navigation, performance and mobile ready. Though it isn't a solution as to 'how' to draw the org chart. However, what is nice about it is that you can feed it image tiles or canvas. Which gives us some choice.

So in the end it is likely that I'll be using image titles to begin with and then migrating to canvas... while keeping my eye on performance advancements in SVG.